# How do I skip creating makefile in extconf.rb

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am writing a gem that depends on utmpx. But I have seen that on my Android's termux environment there's no utmpx. So I want to just skip the makefile creation and show the user warning about the problem.

My extconf looks kind of like this:

```
require 'mkmf'

unless have_const('linux') || RbConfig::CONFIG['arch'].to_s[/linux/]
    abort('Platform is not linux')
end

unless have_header('utmpx.h') && have_header('ruby.h')
    puts("Your system doesn't have utmpx.h. Sorry but you can't use Login")
else
    create_makefile 'login'
end
```

But the else block makes the whole gem uninstallable. The command `gem install` just exists.

How do I check and skip the makefile creation and successfully compile other C modules on OS that missing the header utmpx.h?

Comment: Using `unless` with an `else` is mind-bending. Consider switching the blocks and use `if` instead.

Comment: Could it be the first test properly aborts, but the second doesn't?

Comment: No, actually the first test works because termux is a linux env. But the 2nd one doesn't work because termux doesn't provide utmpx.I have seen if I don't create a makefile inside extconf.rb, it exists with status 1.